# Как в Си изменить кодировку строки (char*) из cp1251 в utf-8?

Tags: c, кодировка, utf-8

По моей задаче в dll-функцию поступает строка в кодировке Windows 1251, её нужно перекодировать в Utf-8.

Comment: А лобовой метод — задать константой таблицу типа u_int_32 1251toutf8[256], заполнить её (на этапе написания кода) UTF-ными кодами и выбирать элемент массива по коду символа в кодировке 1251 — почему-либо не хотите использовать?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, в utf-8 символ может занимать разное количество байт, нужно еще хранить это количество.

Comment: @insolor, что бы вы предложили?

Comment: @insolor да, не учёл. А подход "если в старших байтах нули, то они не нужны" работать не будет?

Comment: @insolor но да, конечно, чисто табличной подстановкой уже не обойтись...

Comment: @Antinet, массив структур, где вторым полем хранится количество байт в символе. Еще один вариант - делать таблицу соответствия исходного символа в utf-32, а потом смотреть по каким правилам utf-32 превращается в utf-8, и применять их к коду символа в utf-32.

Comment: Просто создайте массив `static const char *rtab[128] = {"...", "...", .. };` и заполните его utf-8 последовательностями для каждого символа cp-1251 с кодами 128...255. При перекодировке создавайте новую строку (в принципе она может оказаться в 3 раза больше исходной) путем копирования строк (без завершающего нуля) из перекодировочной таблицы